# Unlock android pattern after changing Gmail Password

Tags: recovery-mode, 2.3-gingerbread, pattern-lock, samsung-galaxy-y, google-account

My little brother had put a pattern lock on my old phone. I can't lose any data from that phone as It has many important contacts in it. so I'm not going for a factory reset. I had recently changed my password of my gmail account. Now I cannot access my phone through that gmail account. What can I do? The phone is Samsung Galaxy y with android 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On older Android devices, if you lock your phone using Google's *find my device* you'll be able to choose a new password, and you'll then be able to access your phone.

Go to [android.com/devicemanager](http://android.com/devicemanager) enter your email address and password. Now, press on *lock*. You will now see an option to put in a password to lock your phone with. After filling it out and pressing *lock*, You should be able to unlock your device with the password you chose.